How can I get values from Vaadin Web Components on POST on a regular html page (no java)?
I'm trying to use vaadin web components on a web page. On POST, component vaadin-combo-box sends the label selected, not the value; and vaadin-select is not in the POST values.
Latest vaadin 24.3.10 components (on Bun / Elysia behind a Caddy proxy)
I reduced my code to this smaller page to test. It includes 4 vaadin components: text-field, radio-group, select and combo-box.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vaadin Debug</title>

    <!-- include all vaadin core components -->
    <script type="module" src="/assets/vaadin-resources.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body style="font-family: var(--lumo-font-family); color: var(--lumo-body-text-color); background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);"></body>

<div style="width:600px; margin: 0 auto" class="border border-contrast-80 border-primary bg-base rounded-l shadow-m">
    <div class="">
        <form id="myForm" name="object-form" action="/partials/object/Entity/0000" method="post">

            <vaadin-text-field id='vaadin-text-field' name='vaadin-text-field' label='vaadin-text-field'>
            </vaadin-text-field>

            <vaadin-combo-box id='vaadin-combo-box' name='vaadin-combo-box' label='vaadin-combo-box'>
            </vaadin-combo-box>
            <script>
                comboBox = document.querySelector('#vaadin-combo-box');
                comboBox.items = [
                    { value: 'a38e43f4-cffd-11ee-baef-1fedb4776d81', label: 'France' },
                    { value: '05cc2734-f295-11ee-bcda-239311358179', label: 'Germany' },
                    { value: '05d11b40-f295-11ee-bcda-674883960b70', label: 'Spain' }
                ];
                comboBox.value = 'a38e43f4-cffd-11ee-baef-1fedb4776d81';
                console.log("vaadin-combo-box")
            </script>

            <vaadin-select id='vaadin-select' name='vaadin-select' label='vaadin-select'>
            </vaadin-select>
            <script>
                select = document.querySelector('#vaadin-select');
                select.items = [
                    {  label: 'Label A', value: 'ce1521d8-cffd-11ee-baef-477d625ddaa8' },
                    {  label: 'Label B', value: 'ce2e4046-cffd-11ee-baef-93b6cbfb74ea' },
                    {  label: 'Label C', value: '45de575e-ea28-11ee-8718-df0dd9251f5f' }
                ];
                select.value = 'ce1521d8-cffd-11ee-baef-477d625ddaa8';
                console.log("vaadin-select updated")                    
            </script>

            <vaadin-radio-group id='vaadin-radio-group' name='vaadin-radio-group' label='vaadin-radio-group'>
                <vaadin-radio-button value="v1" label="Value 1" checked></vaadin-radio-button>
                <vaadin-radio-button value="v2" label="Value 2"></vaadin-radio-button>
                <vaadin-radio-button value="v3" label="Value 3"></vaadin-radio-button>
            </vaadin-radio-group>

            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting

                console.log("Values of elements");
                console.log('vaadin-text-field:', document.querySelector('#vaadin-text-field').value);
                console.log('vaadin-combo-box:', document.querySelector('#vaadin-combo-box').value);
                console.log('vaadin-select:', document.querySelector('#vaadin-select').value);
                console.log('vaadin-radio-group:', document.querySelector('#vaadin-radio-group').value);

                console.log("Form values");
                const formData = new FormData(this);
                for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
                    console.log(key, value);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Button Save displays this in console:
Values of elements
vaadin-text-field: MyText
vaadin-combo-box: a38e43f4-cffd-11ee-baef-1fedb4776d81
vaadin-select: ce1521d8-cffd-11ee-baef-477d625ddaa8
vaadin-radio-group: v1

Form values
vaadin-text-field MyText
vaadin-combo-box France
vaadin-radio-group-18 v1

POSTed values are wrong:

include labels, not values
don't include value or label from vaadin-select

Result should be:
vaadin-text-field: MyText
vaadin-combo-box: a38e43f4-cffd-11ee-baef-1fedb4776d81
vaadin-select: ce1521d8-cffd-11ee-baef-477d625ddaa8
vaadin-radio-group: v1


I don't think the Vaadin web components are meant to be used as fancy
replacement for regular input elements for a form-tag. And while some may be
using standard HTML input, that the browser can pick up with the "form
machinery" others don't. So you would have to use the API the Vaadin web
components provide instead of the one your browser provides.

Split in 2 questions on GitHub, https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/7377 (combo-box) and https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/7378 (select).

Got an answer on gtihub: "The vaadin-select web component doesn't support form submission properly as it's not using  element.
Consider using formdata event to set value corresponding to vaadin-select manually as a workaround."
So while these components are amazing, I'm not so sure they should be called "web components" as they don't behave as real components. I hope that webawesome components will keep their promise...
